Determine a linear transformation such that $Im(f) = \mathbb{H}$ and $f(\mathbb{S}) \subseteq \mathbb{T}$
I am asked to determine $\textbf{if possible}$ a linear transformation
f : $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ such that $Im(f) = \mathbb{H}$ and $f\left(\mathbb{S}\right) \subseteq \mathbb{T}$
$\mathbb{H}$, $\mathbb{S}$, and $\mathbb{T}$ being:
$\mathbb{H} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x_1 + x_2 - x_3 + x_4 = 0\}$
$\mathbb{S} = \langle (1,1,0,1),(0,1,-1,2) \rangle$
$\mathbb{T} = \langle (2,1,1,0),(1,1,0,0) \rangle$
Little summary of what I did
I found a basis for $\mathbb{H}$
$\mathbb{H} = \langle(1,0,1,0),(0,1,1,0),(0,0,1,1)\rangle$
I found a basis for the intersection of H and T
$\mathbb{H} \cap \mathbb{T} = \langle (-1,0,-1,0) \rangle$
Little summary of what I have thought about the problem:
to uniquely identify a linear transformation, we need to represent it based on a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$.
$\textbf{I was taught in class this theorem}$:
Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces. If $\{\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, \dots, \mathbf{v}_n\}$ is a basis of $V$ and $\mathbf{w}_1, \mathbf{w}_2, \dots, \mathbf{w}_n$ are vectors in $W$ (not necessarily distinct), then there exists a unique linear transformation $f : V \to W$ such that:
$
\begin{cases}
f(\mathbf{v}_1) = \mathbf{w}_1, \\
f(\mathbf{v}_2) = \mathbf{w}_2, \\
\vdots \\
f(\mathbf{v}_n) = \mathbf{w}_n.
\end{cases}
$
OK, back from what I was saying, we need to define the linear transformation based on a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$, and two of the slots for this basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ are being occupied by the vectors from $\mathbb{S}$, that is because of the $f\left(\mathbb{S}\right) \subseteq \mathbb{T}$ requirement and because $\dim\left(\mathbb{S}\right) = 2$, also I wanted to point out something obvious but by rank nullity the kernel has to be unidimensional, because the domain is $\mathbb{R}^4$ and because H has dimension three.
Lastly I will share what I have tried:
$\begin{cases}
f(1,1,0,1) = (-1,0,-1,0)\\
f(1,0,1,0) = (0,1,1,0)\\
f(0,0,1,0) = (0,0,1,1)\\
f(0,0,0,1) = (0,0,0,0)
\end{cases}$
basically I tried mapping the first vector of $\mathbb{S}$ to the vector from $\mathbb{H} \cap \mathbb{T}$, mapping the second vector of $\mathbb{S}$ to the second vector from $\mathbb{H}$ and mapping $\mathbf{e}_3$ and $\mathbf{e}_4$ to the third vector of $\mathbb{H}$ and to the null vector respectively
$\mathbf{e}_3$ being the third vector from standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$
$\mathbf{e}_4$ being the fourth vector from standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$
But as you can tell the second image, (0,1,1,0), is not contained in $\mathbb{T}$ , thus, making the answer I provided $\textbf{incorrect}$
for example if you repeat the first image for both f(s1) and f(s2) you will not be satisfying the Im(f) = H condition
What do you guys think? is this even possible? how do I approach this?

the big clue that I received from my friend is : f(s2) = (0,0,0,0), because zero vector is of course contained in T making f(s1) and f(s2) images contained in T, while still satisfying the Im(f) = H condition

A friend of mines told be that: $\mathbf{0} \subset \mathbb{T}$
$\begin{cases} 
f(1,1,0,1) = (1,0,1,0) \\
f(0,1,-1,2) = (0,0,0,0) \\
f(0,0,1,0) = (0,1,1,0) \\
f(0,0,0,1) = (0,0,1,1) \end{cases}$
here we can see that the vectors (1,1,0,1), (0,1,-1,2), (0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1) are not multiples of each other,
this four vectors $\textbf{form a basis of }$ $\mathbb{R}^4$
$(1,0,1,0) \subset \mathbb{T}$ and $(1,0,1,0) \subset \mathbb{H}$
$(0,0,0,0) \subset \mathbb{T}$
since $\mathbb{H} = \langle (1,0,1,0), (0,1,1,0), (0,0,1,1) \rangle$
$(0,1,1,0), (0,0,1,1) \subset \mathbb{H}$
let $B = \{ (1,1,0,1), (0,1,-1,2), (0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1) \}$
$\textbf{here we look for coordinates in basis B of a generic vector of } \mathbb{R}^4$
$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = \alpha(1,1,0,1) + \beta(0,1,-1,2) + \gamma(0,0,1,0) + \delta(0,0,0,1) \iff \begin{cases} \alpha = x_1 \\ \alpha + \beta = x_2 \\ -\beta + \gamma = x_3 \\ \alpha + 2\beta + \delta = x_4 \end{cases}$
with $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \in \mathbb{R}$
$\begin{cases} \alpha = x_1 \\ \beta = x_2 - x_1 \\ \gamma = x_3 + x_2 -x_1 \\ \delta = x_4 - 2(x_2-x_1) - x_1 \implies \delta = x_4 - 2x_2 + x_1 \end{cases}$
$\textbf{We solve the system and we obtain } \alpha = x_1, \beta = x_2 - x_1, \gamma = x_3+x_2-x_1 \textbf{ and } \delta = x_4+x_1-2x_2$
$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = x_1 \cdot (1,1,0,1) + (x_2 - x_1) \cdot (0,1,-1,2) + (x_3 + x_2 - x_1) \cdot (0,0,1,0) + (x_4+x_1-2x_2) \cdot (0,0,0,1)$
$\textbf{we apply f to the equation (since is linear map we separate the sum and scalars out)}$
$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = x_1f(1,1,0,1) + (x_2-x_1)f(0,1,-1,2) + (x_3+x_2-x_1)f(0,0,1,0) + (x_4+x_1-2x_2)f(0,0,0,1)$
$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = x_1 \cdot (1,0,1,0) + (x_2-x_1) \cdot (0,0,0,0) + (x_3+x_2-x_1) \cdot (0,1,1,0) + (x_4+x_1-2x_2) \cdot (0,0,1,1)$
$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (x_1,0,x_1,0) + (0,x_3+x_2-x_1,x_3+x_2-x_1,0) + (0,0,x_4+x_1-2x_2,x_4+x_1-2x_2)$
$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (x_1,x_3+x_2-x_1,x_1+x_3+x_2-x_1+x_4+x_1-2x_2,x_4+x_1-2x_2)$
$\textbf{this is my final answer}$
$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (x_1,x_3+x_2-x_1,x_3-x_2+x_4+x_1,x_4+x_1-2x_2)$
$\textbf{verifying if it satisfies the requested conditions}$
$f(1,1,0,1) = (1,0+1-1,0-1+1+1,1+1-2) = (1,0,1,0)$
$f(0,1,-1,2) = (0,-1+1+0,-1-1+2+0,2+0-2) = (0,0,0,0)$
$f(0,0,1,0) = (0,1+0+0,1+0+0+0,0+0+0) = (0,1,1,0)$
$f(0,0,0,1) = (0,0+0+0,0+0+1+0,1+0+0) = (0,0,1,1)$

Extend the basis of $\mathbb{S}$ to that of $\mathbb{R^4}$ with $v_3, v_4$. We will work with this basis: $\{(1,1,0,1), (0,1,-1,2), v_3, v_4\}$. Let the first two basis vectors be $v_1, v_2$.
Define $f: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ as $$f(c_1v_1 +c_2v_2 + c_3v_3 +c_4v_4) = (c_1+c_2)(1,0,1,0) + c_3 (0,1,1,0) + c_4 (0,0,1,1)$$
This is a linear map as $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$ and any vector can be expressed as a unique linear combination of these.
Note that the image of $f$ is a linear combination of the basis vectors of $\mathbb{H}$. Thus, $Im (f) = \mathbb{H}$. If $x ∈ \mathbb{S}$, then $c_3 = c_4 =0$ as $v_1, v_2$ are a basis for it. Thus, $f(x) = c(1,0,1,0) \in \mathbb{H} ∩ \mathbb{T} ⊂ \mathbb{T}$ for some scalar $c$.
